# contact form 7 submit input expanding and adding icon on hover

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to get the submit input on contact form 7 to expand and show an icon on hover. I have searched around and come up empty so far. If anyone here could help me I would really appreciate it.

**Here is what I want it to look like:**
*A button from the Divi builder on the Divi theme.*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOkma.png)

**Submit to be changed:**
*Contact form 7 on Divi theme*

[form with submit button that needs to be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHvur.png)

If anyone can help I would really appreciate it.

The website is elitesecurityalarms.com and it currently has a coming soon page up, however, if anyone wants to take a look at the site and help me out I will take that page down for now.

If I haven't given you enough information please just ask me for anything else you need.

Comment: you can you css3 or jquery. didnt you try

Answer (score 0):

add css and add icon in button in html.

if you dosen't have icon css add first it into head

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
</head>

    <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-share-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>send</button>
    <style>
    .btn i{
        display:none;
    }
    .btn:hover i{
        display:inline-block;
    }
    </style>
```